# In line H2 and H3 tags, H3 wrap the H2 to fit the container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to keep H2 and H3 in line and if large amount of text, it should wrap around the H2 tag and the container as showing the image.

Applied the `display:inline-block` but text wrapping is not work for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/4vTZA/

[image]

Comment: I donk know if i got you right but i edited your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4vTZA/2/

Comment: Should the teaser really be a `<h3>` in this case? As far as I know H3 is meant for headers on a lower level than H2, not for the initial paragraph of the content.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to `float` the h2 element in this case:

```
h2 { float:left;}
h3 { display:inline; }
```

You'll also want to give them identical `line-height` to prevent the h2 from *consuming* multiple lines:

```
h2, h3 { line-height:20px; }
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4vTZA/7/).

Answer (score 1):

In your code-

```
div {margin:20px;}
h2 ,h3{display:inline;,float:left;}
h2
{
    font-weight:bolder;

}
```

You are going to do it easily. Making more easy for you- http://jsfiddle.net/4vTZA/6/